# Having issue with devart connector in SSIS to Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Not able to connect to bigquery from SSIS dataflow component which is asking for "Refresh Token cannot be empty". Can someone help to resolve this?

Comment: Pleas add a minimum of code and errormessages, to make it easier to understand and answer you question

Comment: I have downloaded the Devart Bigquery components -- https://www.devart.com/ssis/download.html into visual studio(SSIS). I tried creatig new connection managers to bigquery where it asks for porjectid, datasetid and also Refresh Token. ut not sure how to generate the refresh token in bigquery. below is the error msg i get in SSIS -- "Refresh Token cannot be empty"